# iOS swipe back gesture with Custom page route

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to use Android `Page Transition` on iOS. i set `fullscreenDialog to true` this works well but the Swipe back gesture on iOS is disabled. How can i enable it back still using the Android Page Transition.

```
Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Chat(
                                  peerid: peerid,
                                  userid: widget.matchesId,
                                ),
                                fullscreenDialog: true
                              ),
                            );
```

Also i have try to use [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition) still yet getting the-same result. The swipe back gesture on iOS still disabled...